# Kubernetes nginx ingress -> internal haproxy service with SSL passthrough -> external backend server

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ssl, haproxy

I've been struggling with the following scenario for a while, but getting stuck at the finish line.

Essentially, I have deployed an nginx ingress controller, an HAProxy service and an HAProxy deployment. HAProxy is deployed BEHIND nginx (just go with it...) and everything is deployed perfectly fine.

I have a backend server at backend.com serving HTTP traffic on port 9000 and HTTPS traffic on port 9001. (See HAProxy configuration below).

Finally, I configured my DNS record for domain mywebsite.com to the IP address of the load balancer of my kubernetes cluster.

The idea is that anyone who surfs mywebsite.com on either port 80 or 443, then that would go to the ingress controller that would then pass the traffic to the HAProxy service which would then fetch the website content from backend.com:9000 (HTTP) or backend.com:9001 (443). the backend server is an Apache webserver with the SSL certificate generated for mywebsite.com installed.

When I surf http://mywebsite.com, everything works fine and the test page is shown in the browser.

However, when I try to go to **https**://mywebsite.com, I get an invalid certificate error with the certificate common name being "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate".

If I run kubectl get ing, I get the following result:

```
NAME                            CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
haproxytest-proxy-ingress-443   <none>   *       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80      11m
haproxytest-proxy-ingress-80    <none>   *       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80      11m
```

I'm running two ingresses with a default backend to the HAProxy service. One on port 80 and one on port 443. This is requirement as we will be adding and removing domains from HAProxy constantly throughout the day, so I cannot hardcode host rules in the ingress. So all traffic has to pass through to HAProxy.

I suspect that because both the ingresses above only show port 80 that that is the reason why HTTPS is not working and a kubernetes generic certificate is showing.

Below are my YAML files:

ingress-haproxy.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: haproxytest-proxy-ingress-80
  namespace: haproxytest
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: haproxytest-haproxy-service
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/linode-loadbalancer-proxy-protocol: v1
    
  labels:
    name: haproxytest-ingress-80

spec:

  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: haproxytest-haproxy-service
      port:
        number: 80

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: haproxytest-proxy-ingress-443
  namespace: haproxytest
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: haproxytest-haproxy-service
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/linode-loadbalancer-proxy-protocol: v1
    
  labels:
    name: haproxytest-ingress-443

spec:

  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: haproxytest-haproxy-service
      port:
        number: 443
```

service-haproxy.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: haproxytest-haproxy-service
  namespace: haproxytest
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  selector:
    app: haproxytest-haproxy
  ports:

  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

deployment-haproxy.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: haproxytest-haproxy
  namespace: haproxytest
  labels:
    app: haproxytest-haproxy
spec:
  serviceName: haproxytest-haproxy
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: haproxytest-haproxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: haproxytest-haproxy
    spec:
      containers:


      - name: haproxytest
        image: privatehub/haproxytest:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
```

My nginx helm deployment configuration looks like this:

```
# Ingress Controller
controller:

  config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
    
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"

  extraArgs:
    default-backend-service: "haproxytest/haproxytest-haproxy-service"
    enable-ssl-passthrough: "true"

  defaultBackend:
    enabled: false
  
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/linode-loadbalancer-proxy-protocol: v1
```

And finally, my HAProxy configuration is as follows:

```
global
  daemon
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  master-worker
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  stats timeout 30s
  log 127.0.0.1 local2

defaults
  log global
  option tcplog
  mode tcp
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 60s
  option http-server-close
  option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
  option redispatch
  retries 3
  timeout http-request 10s
  timeout queue 1m
  timeout http-keep-alive 10s
  timeout check 10s
  maxconn 3000

frontend https
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend https_backend_port_443 if { req.ssl_sni -i mywebsite.com }

frontend http
  mode http
  bind *:80
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  use_backend http_backend_port_80 if { req.hdr(host) -i mywebsite.com }

backend https_backend_port_443
  mode tcp
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server backend_port_443_server backend.com:9001 weight 100

backend http_backend_port_80
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1
  server backend_port_80_server backend.com:9000 weight 100
```

It is important that PROXY Protocol v1 is working and that the client's real IP is passed from nginx -> haproxy -> backend server.

But first things's first, can anyone help me understand why the SSL passthrough is not working with the above config? Appreciate the help.